# Google feeds API javascript error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, google-feed-api

I have been using google's `ajax feed api` to add an rss feed to a site.

I have used it to show a scrolling headline on the sidebar then used it again to add a full list of headlines of one of the pages. The site is http://www.accordhospice.org.uk/

It works fine but in `ie8` its showing this javascript error which im not sure about:

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;
>   GTB7.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR
>   2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729;
>   AskTbSTK3/5.9.1.14019) Timestamp: Wed,
>   6 Jul 2011 11:04:00 UTC
>
> Message: Object required Line: 121
>   Char: 7 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://www.accordhospice.org.uk/

Answer (score 0):

http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.accordhospice.org.uk%2F

the feed doesnot validate. it may be the reason.
but it is working when I test here.
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#feed_control
thats all I can say without your code.